# Webhook not working on python telegram bot

Tags: python, tcp, telegram, webhooks, telegram-bot

Please, someone help me with this, I'am really struggling for hours by now. Don't know what to do anymore, searched every page everywhere, still no solution.

I have a telegram BOT which I'am migrating from getUpdates() to a webhook. Here goes the code I'am executing (it works, you will see ahead):

```
BOT_TOKEN = 'xxxx' #no show
HOST     = 'y.y.y.y' #no show
PORT     = 443
CERT     = '/home/bot/scripts/python/cert.pem'
CERT_KEY = '/home/bot/scripts/python/private.key'

bot = telegram.bot.Bot(token=TOKEN)
updater = Updater(bot=bot)
updater.start_webhook( listen=HOST,
                       port=PORT, url_path=BOT_TOKEN,
                       key=CERT_KEY, cert=CERT,
                       webhook_url='https://%s:%s/%s'%(HOST,PORT,BOT_TOKEN)
                     )

updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
updater.idle()
```

The Webhook starts as the DEBUG shows:

```
[root@rrpump python]# python3.6 bot_telegram.py
2018-03-06 16:04:04,243 - telegram.ext.dispatcher - DEBUG - Setting singleton dispatcher as <telegram.ext.dispatcher.Dispatcher object at 0x7fd490525ef0>
2018-03-06 16:04:04,243 - JobQueue - DEBUG - JobQueue thread started
2018-03-06 16:04:04,243 - telegram.ext.updater - DEBUG - dispatcher - started
2018-03-06 16:04:04,244 - telegram.ext.updater - DEBUG - updater - started
2018-03-06 16:04:04,244 - telegram.ext.updater - DEBUG - Updater thread started
2018-03-06 16:04:04,247 - telegram.ext.dispatcher - DEBUG - Dispatcher started
2018-03-06 16:04:04,263 - telegram.bot - DEBUG - Entering: set_webhook
2018-03-06 16:04:04,265 - telegram.vendor.ptb_urllib3.urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): api.telegram.org
2018-03-06 16:04:04,704 - telegram.vendor.ptb_urllib3.urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - https://api.telegram.org:443 "POST /botxxxx/setWebhook HTTP/1.1" 200 57
2018-03-06 16:04:04,706 - telegram.bot - DEBUG - True
2018-03-06 16:04:04,706 - telegram.bot - DEBUG - Exiting: set_webhook
2018-03-06 16:04:04,706 - telegram.utils.webhookhandler - DEBUG - Webhook Server started.
```

But when I send a /start command to my bot, nothing arrives.

Then, I openned the 443 port on my server:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

And verified if my bot script was listening to that port:

```
[root@rrpump bot]# lsof -i | grep python3.6
python3.6 30598     root    7u  IPv4 2781012079      0t0  TCP rrpump.com:https (LISTEN)
python3.6 30598     root    9u  IPv6 2781012225      0t0  TCP rrpump.com:43682->[2001:67c:4e8:f004::9]:https (ESTABLISHED)
```

**Yes, it was. But still, my bot was not responding to /start commands through telegram.**

Then, I tryied POSTMAN and simulated a /start command sent directly to my webhook just like explained [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks#testing-your-bot-with-updates):

[image: postman /start command sent]

No success. The webhook still don't receive anything. Something is clear until now: It is not a problem with api.telegram.org servers. When I do a updater.bot.getWebhookInfo(), I can see there are 14 pending updates, all my 14 '/starts' I sent to my bot through telegram:

```
print(updater.bot.getWebhookInfo().to_dict())
{'has_custom_certificate': True,
 'last_error_date': 1520355514,
 'last_error_message': 'Connection timed out',
 'max_connections': 40,
 'pending_update_count': 14,
 'url': 'https://y.y.y.y:443/xxxx'}
```

Then I tried to send a message with '/start' to my webhook directly from inside my server to itself like [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks#testing-your-bot-with-updates):

```
[root@rrpump bot]# curl -v -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache"  -d '{
> "update_id":10000,
> "message":{
>   "date":1441645532,
>   "chat":{
>      "last_name":"Test Lastname",
>      "id":1111111,
>      "type": "private",
>      "first_name":"Test Firstname",
>      "username":"Testusername"
>   },
>   "message_id":1365,
>   "from":{
>      "last_name":"Test Lastname",
>      "id":1111111,
>      "first_name":"Test Firstname",
>      "username":"Testusername"
>   },
>   "text":"/start"
> }
> }' "https://y.y.y.y/xxxx"

* About to connect() to y.y.y.y port 443 (#0)
*   Trying y.y.y.y...
* Connected to y.y.y.y (y.y.y.y) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* skipping SSL peer certificate verification
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=y.y.y.y 1,O=Example Brooklyn Company,L=Brooklyn,ST=New York,C=US
*       start date: Mar 06 13:54:03 2018 GMT
*       expire date: Mar 06 13:54:03 2019 GMT
*       common name: y.y.y.y
*       issuer: CN=y.y.y.y,O=Example Brooklyn Company,L=Brooklyn,ST=New York,C=US
> POST /xxxx HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: y.y.y.y
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Cache-Control: no-cache
> Content-Length: 392
>
* upload completely sent off: 392 out of 392 bytes
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Server: WebhookHandler/1.0 Python/3.6.4
< Date: Tue, 06 Mar 2018 16:52:55 GMT
<
* Closing connection 0
```

**And the webhook was triggered:**

```
2018-03-06 16:52:55,844 - telegram.utils.webhookhandler - DEBUG - Webhook triggered
2018-03-06 16:52:55,844 - telegram.utils.webhookhandler - DEBUG - 93.188.166.161 - - "POST /415365952:AAFMeP6TVyhey4D1MNAaqhhiH0lh4EUvLVE HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2018-03-06 16:52:55,844 - telegram.utils.webhookhandler - DEBUG - Webhook received data: {
"update_id":10000,
"message":{
  "date":1441645532,
  "chat":{
     "last_name":"Test Lastname",
     "id":1111111,
     "type": "private",
     "first_name":"Test Firstname",
     "username":"Testusername"
  },
  "message_id":1365,
  "from":{
     "last_name":"Test Lastname",
     "id":1111111,
     "first_name":"Test Firstname",
     "username":"Testusername"
  },
  "text":"/start"
}
}
```

*Now.. the question is: how could my server be listening on port 443 only for itself? Why isn't it listening to external addresses just like I saw in the command lsof -i | python3.6?

This command also shows that:

```
[root@rrpump bot]# lsof -i:443
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
python3.6 30644 root    8u  IPv4 2785755157      0t0  TCP y.y.y.y:https (LISTEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me:

```
updater = Updater("xxxx")    
updater.start_webhook(
    listen='0.0.0.0',
    port=8443,
    url_path='xxxx',
    key='private.key',
    cert='cert.pem',
    webhook_url='https://y.y.y.y:8443/xxxx'
)
updater.idle()
```

where y.y.y.y is external IP of server running the bot code and xxxx is the token.
I had to port forward 8443 port in my router, because the mentioned server is connected to the router and NAT is enabled.